# Django. Сумма всех заказов у клиента

Tags: python-3.x, django

Всем привет)

Не могу разобраться как реализовать сумму всех заказов у клиента. Пока дорыл до такого "состояния".

В итоге я получаю QuerySet с суммой заказов ВСЕХ клиентов, а мне надо только для одного клиента.

**models.py**

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=50, db_index=True)

    def get_summ(self):
        clients = Client.objects.annotate(total_summa=Sum('order__summa'))
        return clients

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Клиент")
    summa = models.FloatField(max_length=20, default='0')
```

**client_detail.html**

```html
<div class="mr-auto">Сумма заказов</div>
  <div class="bd-highlight">
     {% for res in client.get_summ %}
        <span class="badge badge-success mr-0">{{ res.total_summa }} руб.</span>
     {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Client.order_set.all.aggregate(Sum('summa'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/